# Look for the appropriate table to store data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently new with PHP and MySQL and I am trying to create a system for time logs (to record time in and out).

I have created a table for users where the accounts of employees are stored and have created different tables named after the different users. What I want to do is store the time in and out to the table named after the user that is logged in.
(User(currently logged in) = Employee1. The time in and out data then should be stored in the table named "Employee1".

How do I search for the right table base on the user's username with PHP?

Comment: I'm confused. You created a table for users where the accounts of employees are stored. That sounds good. But, you also created a table per user in your database too? Is that right? So, if you have 100 employees, you have 100 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **don't** want to use a different table for every user. Have one table called `employees` that looks something like this:

```
    ID    |   First_name    |    Last_name    |    Favorite_ice_cream
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1             Bill            Joneston               Chocolate
    2             Harry           Smitters               Sherbert
```

This table stores the employee's basic information. Note that the ID is unique for every employee.

Then have another table called `time_logs` that looks something like:

```
Employee_ID    |   Time_In    |    Time_Out    |     Date
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1               8:00            5:00           2014-05-05
    2               8:30            5:30           2014-05-05
```

Now you can just use these two tables to track employee time logs.

To get `Harry Smitter's` time stats for May 5th, based on his name, run a query like this:

```
SELECT
    log.time_in,
    log.time_out
FROM time_logs log
JOIN employees e ON e.id = log.employee_id
WHERE e.first_name = 'Harry'
    AND e.last_name = 'Smitters'
    AND log.date = '2014-05-05'
```

Note that, if there happens to be two 'Harry Smitters' with stats for May 5th, you will get both of their stats.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but to add, you can have a second table that defines the Employee_ID as a dimension. This is where you can include additional attributes of the Employee_ID such as FirstName, LastName and so forth.

Comment: @Fastidious that's true I've updated my answer to help illustrate this

Comment: This is absolutely great. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3627135 Great, glad I could help. I have also added a little more info if it is helpful :)

Comment: @MarkM, a follow up question regarding your answer, how can I set Bill(ID:1) on the 1st table, to still have Employee_ID # 1 on the second table? Should I set a condition that if Bill is logged in, then the data to be stored on the 2nd table will have a value of 1 on the Employee_ID?

Comment: @user3627135 Yes, exactly. When Bill gets hired, you add him to the `employees` table and he gets a unique ID. Then, everytime Bill logs in, you insert a new row into `time_logs` with the date, time_in, and Bill's ID. When he logs out, find that row and update time_out. This is a simplified explanation but I think you have the right idea. Keep in mind that there are other complications to consider when building a relational database. I would google around for tutorials on database design with mysql. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: I am trying it right now. Again, thank you for your time and your response.